# What is unclear in this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

I recently asked the question *[How do I produce plain binary from object files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442242/how-to-produce-plain-binary-from-object-files)* on Stack Overflow. It was put on hold as it was considered to be "unclear". Can anyone well aware with the rules of Stack Overflow, tell me what was the reason for closing the question?

I haven't asked vaguely, and I have correctly defined what I want. I replied to the comments correctly, being as specific as possible.

Even the [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) documentation clearly states what the plain binary file format is: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html

The problem I have asked is perfectly valid and might prove to be useful in the future.

If anybody could review my question and tell me What was the problem with my question or was there any alternate way of asking this question, I'll be more than grateful to them.

Comment: Why didn't put the reference to NASM plain binary into the question? I'm sure that would've cleared things up. "Plain binary" can mean a number of things in a number of contexts, and the original question just contained a single sentence with actual information content. This has nothing to do with any rules of SO, people simply found your question too vague.

Comment: Yes, the NASM documentation defines "plain binary" - but your question didn't *mention* NASM. Now that it's been edited (by another user) it's much clearer. Whenever you write a question, remember that the user *only* has as much context as you put into the question.

Comment: I didn't put up the reference to the NASM plain binary mainly because, I never knew it could be interpreted in different ways. Anhyways, people who had that confusion commented and I cleared their confusion by specifying what were the command line options to produce that "plain binary format".

Comment: This topic is absolutely not in my wheelhouse, so I don't know if it's clear enough now for someone familiar with the matter. But I still find it vague. Remember: *you* know what you're talking about, *we* do not. Just add a few more sentences explaining the context and background of how this question came up.

Comment: With my limited knowledge, I could only make out one meaning of the plain binary format. How would someone know that there are multiple meanings of the word they mentioned if they don't have the required knowledge. Anyways, I will try to be as specific as possible in future, but still "closing" the question seems to harsh to me. The close voters could have told this in the comments itself.

Comment: You have quite a number of comments on that question! Just take them to heart, update the question and wait a little for it to be reopened. It already has two reopen votes.

Comment: And especially if you're not familiar with something: provide references and context to clarify what *you think* you're talking about, how you came to the point you're at where you need to ask this question. If you're an expert you can probably laser focus a question with a single sentence; if you're not you better explain your problem in as many different words as necessary to circle in on what you need.

Comment: @deceze I'll keep these points in mind when answering/asking next question. Edited the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, your lack of knowledge doesn't mean that a question that's clear to you will be understandable to others. To most programmers, "binary file" would be the constrast to "text file". Closing the question as unclear is not intended as an insult to you, it just means that the way you've explained the question is not understandable to everyone else.

Comment: However, as a general rule, it's pretty unlikely that a clear question could ever be asked in just 2 lines.